# How to disassemble this eccentric bushing

Tags: bearings, machine-design, machine-elements

This eccentric bushing:

[image]

belongs to the hand crank of this machine:

[image]

It cannot be seen clearly in the photo, but the small blocking bar inside the bushing is not hovering over but rather, is sunk into a notch in the same surface which contains the thread.

I would like to disassemble the bushing, because the crank is badly aligned. **How can I do this? Should I remove the small blocking bar inside in order to disassemble? Do I need a special tool?**

Comment: to me it looks like a shaft key

Comment: May have to temove the assembly to get to the bearing. Given this is the second question you have about this machine, perhaps you should find a workshop manual for it.

Comment: @SolarMike This https://boltontool.com/pdf/SBR1220.pdf is the only manual which I have found: for a machine which "looks similar". It is silent about these bushings. Do you mean that I should take a large wrench and try to pull out the thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "badly aligned"? That's just a key, so there should be nothing (except friction) stopping you from pulling the handle off the shaft...

Comment: @JonathanRSwift After your comment I understood what's going on, wasn't afraid to use a hammer (a wrench wasn't enough) and pulled it off.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance!